# How to style data-table search panel for the whole table?

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, liferay-7.3

The search panel at the top of the table does not appear for the whole table. Just shows till the screen fits and when you scroll, it is not extended.

Here is the data-table code.

```js
$("#standardList").dataTable({
                  "aoColumnDefs": [
                               {
                                targets: ['_all'],
                                "bLengthChange": false, 
                                "bSort": true, 
                                "bFilter": true, 
                                "aaSorting": [],
                                "bAutoWidth": true,
                                "scrollX": true,
                                "oLanguage": {
                                      "sSearch": "Search: ",
                                      "sEmptyTable": "<div class='portlet-msg-alert'>No standards Found</div>" 
                                    },
                                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                            }]
                   });
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH3G3.png

Comment: What's the code for that?

Comment: It will help to know the HTML/CSS/JS framework you are using. Otherwise checkout the position and z-index CSS attributes.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, I assume you are using datatables? If so, https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX should help.

Comment: I have already tried, z-index, ScrollX, and no-wrap option but it does not work.